# How can I add furigana into website content?

Tags: cjk, yahoo-api

I need to make auto furigana view for my Japanese website content. For that I just tried many possible solutions.
In Yahoo's API there is a way of doing it.

```
<?php
$appid = 'My api Key';
$sentence1="日本";
$sentence = mb_convert_encoding($sentence1, 'utf-8', 'auto');
echo $request  = "http://jlp.yahooapis.jp/FuriganaService/V1/furigana?appid=".$appid."&sentence=".urlencode($sentence);
```

But In this Yahoo API, we need to include all content into a variable and split into separate. It makes more time because my content is dynamics.
I need a auto furigana solution like [IPA Furigana](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ipa-furigana/jnnbgnfnncobhklficfkdnclohaklifi) Google Extension.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.furiousgana.com/api/

Adding this here for anyone who might be interested in furigana generation.
You can generate furigana by sending a post request to this 'https://api.furiousgana.com' and setting the body of the data to an object or array.

The English tag is optional.

```
  const query = [
    {
      japanese:'気を付けて',
      english:'Take care!'
    },
    {
      japanese:'お元気ですか？',
      english:'Are you ok?'
    }
  ]
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://api.furiousgana.com',
    data: query
  })
  .then(({data})=>{
    console.log(data) // here is you data
  });
```

The final step would be to parse the generated furigana so that it wraps the content in  &  tags

Answer (score 0):

This github will help full for furigana.
Just pass the variable to the kuroshiro.convert('variable') and then you will get the data with furigana also with ruby tag.

https://github.com/hexenq/kuroshiro.js

Comment: Thanks It will work and I already saw this github and Thanks Once again.